# Difference between sudo in macOS and Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, osx, sudo

I am using Ubuntu (the latest release).

In Ubuntu, I type `gedit filename` and after saving the file, I type `sudo gedit filename` (it gave me a warning), but what surprise me is that, it didn't show me the original file, and give me a "new file"(also named "filename") which is empty. so I get confused, and I try to type `gedit filename`(without `sudo`) again, and the original file shows again. It seems that these "two" files are stored in different place, since I can edit non-sudo file and sudo-file respectively.

The operating above are based on the command-line, and if I open the file via GUI approach, Ubuntu will show me the file which I didn't type `sudo`

But in the case of macOS (macOS 10.13), the `sudo` command is only used to improve permissions, and of course I cannot get "two" different files.

So, can anyone help me on this issue, why using `sudo` command to edit files can lead to such a situation? And does that mean these two files belong to two different users(in Ubuntu situation)?

Comment: Are you doing this at the same location? Do `pwd` in both terminals first. And please don't post images of text. Or at least make them minimum size.

Comment: It looks like `sudo` on the two systems are configured differently.  The Ubuntu configuration is obviously resetting the `HOME` environment variable to home of the target user (root).

Comment: Run `pwd; sudo pwd` on both systems and compare.

Comment: @Tomaz yes, and i access to both two "files" to edit and save, as if they are stored in two different places!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong in Ubuntu by using `sudo gedit`. You shouldn't use sudo to open graphical applications as root because this is a known cause of file corruption. That's why you get a warning like this in Ubuntu when you run `sudo gedit filename` .

```
** (gedit:14140): WARNING **: 16:10:13.541: Set document metadata failed:  
Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported
```

Nautilus Admin (*nautilus-admin*) is a simple Python extension for the Nautilus file manager that adds some administrative actions to the right-click menu:

- Open as Administrator: opens a folder in a new Nautilus window     running with administrator (root) privileges.
- Edit as Administrator: opens a file in a Gedit window running     with administrator (root) privileges.

To install Nautilus Admin in all  currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install nautilus-admin
```